# Plain Old Ruby data load local in File

Tags: mysql, ruby

Problem: MYSQL and RUBY (not with rails?) gives error:

The used command is not allowed with this MySQL version (Mysql::Error)

Dear Friends,

1. I can Issue this from the command line but NOT from my ruby (WITHOUT rails).

   mysql> Load data local infile 'remediation_rewrite.csv' into table report.remediation IGNORE 1 lines (MACHINE_NAME , TYPE_OF_ACTION , SCORE , FILE_PATH , MD5,  REGKEY , VThit, action , action_result, action_result_detail, date);
   Query OK, 455168 rows affected, 65535 warnings (22.35 sec)

2) Ruby command that fails for the following reason:

```
column = "(MACHINE_NAME , TYPE_OF_ACTION , SCORE , FILE_PATH , MD5,  REGKEY , VThit, action , action_result, action_result_detail, date)"
    str = "Load data local infile " + "'" + "remediation_rewrite.csv" + "'" + " into table report.remediation" + " IGNORE 1 lines " + "#{column}" + ";";
    p str
    @con = Mysql.new("172.16.10.193", "myusername","xxx", "reporttdatabase")
    @con.options(Mysql::OPT_LOCAL_INFILE, true)
    rs = @con.query(str)
```

Comment: what is the full path to the file? `remediation_rewrite.csv`

Comment: /home/myuser/database_parser/remediation_rewrite.csv

Comment: I added the full path and it still doesn't work;

Comment: Generate_Remediation_Report.rb:100:in `query': The used command is not allowed with this MySQL version (Mysql::Error)

Comment: Which gem are you using to execute against MySQL?  It's very possible that it simply doesn't support the `LOAD DATA`  command as it states.  You can try using the 'mysql2' gem.

Comment: I even switched my code to mysql2  Remediation Table Created Remediation Table Created "Load data local infile '/home/xx/database_parser/remediation_rewrite.csv' into table report.remediation IGNORE 1 lines (MACHINE_NAME , TYPE_OF_ACTION , SCORE , FILE_PATH , MD5,  REGKEY , VThit, action , action_result, action_result_detail, date);"
Generate_Remediation_Report.rb:102:in `query': The used command is not allowed with this MySQL version (Mysql2::Error)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per the ['mysql2' gem documentation](https://github.com/brianmario/mysql2#connection-options), you need to specify `:local_infile` as `true` for security reasons (explained [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/load-data-local.html), and referenced [here](https://github.com/brianmario/mysql2/issues/43)).

Substitute this for your `@con` client object:

```
@con = Mysql2::Client.new(
  host: "172.16.10.193", 
  username: "myusername",
  password: "xxx", 
  database: "reporttdatabase",
  local_infile: true
)
```

Comment: I spent over 6 hours on this problem.  I am sad that it took you only 5 minutes to answer it;  Thank you.